# How to configure CentOS 8 loopback interface

Tags: centos, networking

I can add additional `IPADDRN` entries to `ifcfg-<device>` files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and those IPs will be made available.  Using `ifcfg-lo` does not have the desired effect though, and `nmcli device` shows `lo` is unmanaged.

Per [this discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1650342) I see that RHEL is not going to support systemd-network in version 8, so I can't use a file in `/etc/systemd/network` as nothing reads those (indeed, that directory does not exist--though `/lib/systemd/network` does).

So what is it that brings up `lo` and does it read any configuration files that I'd be able to use to add additional addresses?

I can write my own service to add the addresses as needed, but if there's a way that's already built, I'd be happier using that.

Comment: You can enable what you are looking for with `yum install network-scripts`. That will create the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`.

Comment: @NasirRiley thanks, but I'm hoping to avoid deprecated packages or solutions if possible.  given that it used to be possible with those tools I'm hoping it is still possible if I learn the right way

Comment: Network Manager is used to configure networking by default in RHEL 8 and CentOS 8 but many disable it and use network-scripts instead. I've done this where I work because I'd rather not use Network Manager. There is no right way. Either is sufficient and it just depends on what you prefer.

Comment: I also prefer using NetworkManager but sadly, to manage the loopback interface with an ifcfg-lo file you have to use the old network-scripts package. It bugs me too.

Comment: Since `/sbin/ifup` contains just 2 lines invoking network-manager loading files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` I assume writing a service file is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the best way is to configure a dummy interface, which worked in my case on CentOS8.

From RedHat [dokumentaton:](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/creating-a-dummy-interface_configuring-and-managing-networking)

*A dummy interface provides a device to route packets without actually transmitting them. It enables you to create additional **loopback-like devices** managed by NetworkManager and makes an inactive SLIP (Serial Line Internet Protocol) address look like a real address for local programs.*

```
[root@CentOS8 ~]# nmcli connection add type dummy ifname dummy2 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.5.102/32

[root@CentOS8 ~]# systemctl restart NetworkManager

[root@CentOS8 ~]# nmcli dev status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eth0    ethernet  connected  eth0
dummy2  dummy     connected  dummy-dummy2
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Notice that loopback device remained unmanaged and dummy device picked up its role.

UPDATE:

I was also able to configure additional dummy interface manually by creating the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dummy-dummy44.nmconnection` , where "dummy44" is the name of the new dummy interface, with the following content:

```
[connection]
id=dummy-dummy44
uuid=c5f6f118-9c63-4c33-96f4-cb5e70ae9248
type=dummy
interface-name=dummy44
permissions=

[dummy]

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.105.44/32
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

I have modified the uuid, so that is not same like dummy2 interface.

After the reboot, the physical eth0, and two dummy interfaces were all pingable.

Comment: I like this idea.  I haven't seen how to make the dummy interfaces persistent though.  It looks like people using other systems will use systemd-networkd to manage them persistently, but as noted in the question that doesn't seem to be sufficiently supported on CentOS 8.  Is there a config file available to do this?

Comment: Not really sure why on your system the dummy interface is not persistent. I have just confugured another Centos8 VM (copied/pasted the nmcli command from above) and after the reboot both interfaces survived and are pingable on both IPs.

Comment: @EricRenouf Updated. Looks like it works the manual way as well.